# Point sub domains to local ip

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

so here is the setup
server 1 receives all incoming web users as it's the one that port 80 is forwarded too (apache).

servers 2-4, have various other services, local ip addresses 192.168.0.x, and I'd like to be able to point sub domains to each of them.

so far all i can work out what I need to do is create the sub domains as entries as virtual hosts and then somehow get those rather than pointing to a directory on server1 point them towards the various other servers on the local network, however I can't work out what exactly I need to enter to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com

  ErrorLog    logs/subdomain.example.com_error_log
  CustomLog   logs/subdomain.example.com_log common

  ProxyPass           /     http://192.168.0.x:9090/
  ProxyPassReverse    /     http://192.168.0.x:9090/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i attempt to restart apache2 it gives me the error, "Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."

Comment: inside which it states 'Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration'